# Question for an aggressive humor : You can't unload a truckload of bowling balls with a pitchfork

Tags: humor

I found an humor while reading an essay. But I can't understand the reason why it is funny. Does it need some background knowledge to understand it? I know only it is a kind of sick humor. Could you explain it for me?

The sick "humor" : Q. "What's the difference between a truckload of bowling balls and a truckload of dead babies?"

A. "You can't unload a truckload of bowling balls with a pitchfork."

Comment: I'd be very worried about anyone that genuinely found this funny.

Comment: What's that to do with ELU, btw?

Comment: Off-topic because it's not about the English language or its usage.

Comment: Im sorry then where should I post this question?

Comment: This joke would be (un)funny in any language, the humour doesn't depend on some quirk of English. It's not a play on words. I would describe this type of joke as "black humour": *the juxtaposition of morbid and farcical elements (in writing or drama) to give a disturbing effect.* Pretty tasteless. Sorry, I'm not aware of a forum that focuses on explaining humour.

Comment: Somebody must think it's funny because I've encountered it every ten years or so for at least the past 40 years. A scholar of "humor" tropes might be able to tell you how far back it goes and where it originated. I'm not a scholar, but I vaguely recall a brief vogue (perhaps in the 1970s) for "dead baby" jokes—a type of gross-out humor—of which the bowling ball/pitchfork jest is the only one that seems to have had any real staying power.

Comment: I just did a little searching in the Elephind newspaper database and found a reference from a 1974 college newspaper in Boston to "a pair of youngsters seated across the counter from me (freshmen, I presume) [who] were laughing uproariously over what they call 'dead baby jokes.'" So they have indeed been around for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The need to laugh at things which are tragic, offensive or disgusting is known as "gallows humour" or "black comedy".

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_comedy#Nature_and_functions

The form of the joke is "the difference is a surprising similarity".

Example:

- What is the difference between a violinist and a dog?
- The dog knows when to stop scratching.

Or:

- What is the difference between a violin and a viola?
- The viola burns longer.